# Finding a way to get the Library Version used?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, shared-libraries, version

I am deploying a script on multiple spreadsheets via the Libraries.
But as you may know, there is no way (yet) for the script to know if it's running the latest version.

I am trying to find a way around this by creating my own versioning for my code.
I have a web service giving back the latest version number of my library code so I can compare it, but the onOpen() cannot run fetchURL. I tried opening a spreadsheet that would keep the info, but again the onOpen() do not let you openById...

onOpen() trigger has security limitations that prevent me to consult an external data source that I could use to keep my versioning.

Note: I do not want to use script trigger for the onOpen() event. Script trigger are not copied when the spreadsheet is copied.

So I am running out of ideas on how to check a library version on a onOpen() trigger event by pointing on an external data source (being a url, other spreadsheet - anything!).

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want your script to be able to get the project version that it is running within then please go "star" @Edo 's corresponding [feature request (#1369)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369).  Your star equals a vote for this feature.  (The request is in the official Apps-Script issue tracker, [according](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features) to the official Google Apps Script Support page.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution is to add a getVersion() method to your library and manually update it every time you update the library.

Edited: I see you want to know not just the version but whether this is the latest version. You can store that information in ScriptProperties in the library and have a function like this:

```
function isLatestVersion() {
  return currentVersion == ScriptProperties.getProperty("latestVersion");
}
```

(I'm assuming you are ok with hardcoding currentVersion into the code and changing it each time you redeploy the webapp.) Script properties can be edited via the File > Project Properties menu, and you can change the value without redeploying the script, so by changing latestVersion from that menu you will make old versions suddenly start responding "false" when calling isLatestVersion().

Comment: No the problem is to know if the version of code is the latest. Since we do not have access to Library Versions Numbers, I have to check the information externally in a data source that I would maintain manually that would tell which version number is the latest one. Then I could compare it with the running script version number. The issue is that onEdit() and onOpen() restrictions prevent accessing data with urlfetch or onOpenById(). So I cannot check if my users are running the latest code when they open the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that I know of, which I'm sure I've seen on this forum (will link the thread if I find it), is to provide some mechanism for the user to manually run a script that will take them through the authorisation process. This might be a sheet at the start of the workbook with a button to press and explanatory text. When the script is run, that "splash page" sheet could be deleted by the script itself.

But as a result of that, rather than copying the spreadsheet, you would probably need a script (say, menu-driven) that would create a copy of the spreadsheet with the necessary splash page.

Not ideal, but that's the only thing I could think of.