# Get current script version in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I  have created a library and want to check if others are using the latest version or not. If not, one mail regarding the same should be sent?So, is there a way to get the current version of a Spreadsheet script using Google app script ?

Comment: Why not have the scripts in your library log the version? I don't think there's a method to grab the version of the script itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve information of the versions of a script programmatically by calling [projects.versions.list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/list) in Apps Script API. The [response to that call](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/list#response-body) would get you information on the last version of the script.

But as ross said, there is no method to get the version of the script that is being run. You would have to add that manually to every version you create. For example, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736537/finding-a-way-to-get-the-library-version-used), your script could have a function that returns the current version, and you would have to update this function manually for every new version. You could then compare the current version to the last one, and send the email if they are not the same.

I hope this is of any help.